# How to handle this element?

Tags: automated-tests

Please help me how to handle this element in seleinum

Thanks in advance

[image: image description here]

Comment: Please add more details.. what exactly you want to do with this field in seleinum..

Comment: please add the [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)